# Что быстрее php5-fpm или php 7?

Tags: php, php7, php-fpm

Не могу разобраться с FPM на PHP. Как я понял FPM можно скачать только здесь -
 https://php-fpm.org/downloads/ и последний доступный это для php 5.2.17. Значит для php 7 нету FPM? Или каким-то нехитрым способом его можно пересобрать и получить php7-fpm? Если php 7 нельзя получить с FPM, тогда что быстрее php5-fpm или php 7? Короче, вправьте мне мозги.

Comment: А вам зачем? Я серьезно спрашиваю. У вас прям очень-очень высоконагруженый проект?

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, php7.0-fpm есть (7.1 тоже, да и 7.2 думаю). 
Например в репозиториях Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-fpm

Comment: @RTK Спасибо. В ubuntu php7.1-fpm, в debian только php7.0-fpm.

Comment: @RTK а для винды что-нибудь есть?)

Comment: Php-fpm 7.1 для CentOS: https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо. Хорошая новость, а то я шарился по пакетам CentOS и кроме php5-fpm ничего не нашел.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Всё-таки выберу CentOS для связки nginx+php-fpm+postgres

Comment: @ИванАнтонов для windows php-fpm это php-cgi.exe из официального релиза http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь нужна историческая справка:

В проекте по адресу https://php-fpm.org/downloads/ вы видите максимум бинарники PHP 5.2 потому что после этого FPM был принят в сам PHP и ныне существует именно там. Со статусом `EXPERIMENTAL` наработки были в ветке PHP 5.3.х и уже без этой отметки начиная с [5.4.0 rc2](http://php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-11-29-1)

Поэтому вам не нужно выбирать между PHP7 и PHP-FPM, вы просто пытаетесь искать не там. FPM жив, здоров и весел и я уже очень много лет не видел проектов написанных на PHP, но не использующих FPM.

Answer (score 1):

В контексте пользовательского опыта, разница в производительности той, или иной сборки PHP начинает иметь значение только в трех случаях:

1) У вас ОЧЕНЬ высоконагруженное приложение (в этом случае и вопрос бы не возник, как мне кажется)

2) У вас ОЧЕНЬ долго выполняется конкретный скрипт

3) Вам нужна оптимизация ради оптимизации (имеет право на жизнь, но вызывает недоуменее)

Первый случай не рассматриваем в виду его неуместности.

Третий случай не рассматриваю, поскольку не владею данными нагрузочного тестирования.

Второй случай - это то, про что этот сайт. Приведите код (желательно с указанием узких мест) и сообщество постарается вам помочь.

PS Рассматривайте этот ответ в большей степени как вопрос о конкретизации вашей проблемы. Так как велика вероятность того, что проблема лежит несколько глубже и конкретика позволит найти более оптимальное решение.

Comment: Спасибо за такое рвение, но я только искал php7-fpm и ничего более. А  вопрос "что быстрее php5-fpm или php 7" относится к случаю, если бы php7-fpm не было.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов обновил ответ

Comment: Еще ничего нет, ни строчки кода, я только задумываюсь о сборке :D Интересуюсь со стороны администратора. Я сейчас изучаю nginx, а php-fpm следующий вопрос по значимости для меня.
Потому что хочу связку Debian+Nginx+php-fpm+PostgreSQL.

Comment: Только слышал в debian плохо с поддержкой nginx, но это давний слух и я не знаю, так ли это сейчас. PHP 7 уже давно появился но о fpm версии не слышал, поэтому встал вопрос.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов `debian плохо с поддержкой nginx` опять слухи... идем на офф сайт и [видим, что поддерживаются все последние версии дистра, включая убунту](https://nginx.org/ru/linux_packages.html). @rjhdby, четвертый кейс - "мой", как любителя Nginx, противника "лишней прослойки" и неудобных конфигов апача :)